# Andengine - how to get remaining path on PathModifier.Path

Tags: java, android, andengine, a-star

Is it possible to get remaining path in Andengine on PathModifier.Path during the move ? Could you please show an example ?

Comment: You can get the seconds elapsed PathModifier.getSecondsElapsed() and the Duration, PathModifier.getDuration() and therefore calculate the percentage done and hence how far through the paths you have travelled and what is remaining. Or you could monitor the progress using the IPathModifierListener() on which way points have been started and finished and calculate the remaining path based upon the current position of the Entity. Do you require it as an actual Path() or would time or direct distance remaining suffice?